# Extending LINQ to Nhibernate provider, in combination with Dynamic LINQ problem

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate 3.1.0 and I'm trying to extend the LINQ provider by using `BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod` and extending the `DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry` as explained in [Fabio's post](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html).

For example, to support `ToString()` I've created a `ToStringGenerator` as below.

```
internal class ToStringGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
{
    public ToStringGenerator()
    {
        SupportedMethods = new[]
            {
                ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition<object>(x => x.ToString())
            };
    }

    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method, Expression targetObject, ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments, HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        return treeBuilder.Cast(visitor.Visit(targetObject).AsExpression(), typeof(string));
    }
}
```

and I have registered using

```
internal class CustomLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
{
    public CustomLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry()
    {
        this.Merge(new ToStringGenerator());
    }
}
```

etc. So far this works for "static" queries, I can use it like this:

```
var results = mSession.Query<Project>();
string pId = "1";
results = results.Where(p => p.Id.ToString().Contains(pId));
```

This translates correctly to its SQL counterpart (using SQL Server 2008)

```
where cast(project0_.Id as NVARCHAR(255)) like (''%''+@p0+''%'')
```

The problem arises when I try to use it in combination with Microsoft Dynamic LINQ library (discussed in [this Scott Guthrie's post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)) like this:

```
var results = mSession.Query<Project>();
string pId = "1";
results = results.Where("Id.ToString().Contains(@0)", pId);
```

This results in a **NotSupportedException** with a message of "**System.String ToString()**" (which was the exact same messages I was getting with the static queries before implementing the classes mentioned above). This exception is being thrown with a source of "**NHibernate**" and with the StackTrace at "**at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMethodCallExpression(MethodCallExpression expression)**".

So what am I missing here? What have I done wrong, or what needs to be done to support this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it.
At first I want to thank murki for providing the information which got me on my way!
 The answer lies partly in Fabio's post. To solve this issue you have to use the `RegisterGenerator` instead of the `Merge` method in the `CustomLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry` constructor. My implementation of the `CustomLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry` class is as follows:

```
public class CustomLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
{
    public CustomLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry()
        : base()
    {
        MethodInfo toStringMethod = ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition<int>(x => x.ToString());
        RegisterGenerator(toStringMethod, new ToStringGenerator());
    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the Merge implementation then.

Answer (score 1):

There are two, well defined, separate stages here:

1. Converting the dynamic (string) query into a static expression (done by the Dynamic Linq library)
2. Parsing that into an HqlTree, then executing (done by NHibernate)

Since you have determined that a static expression works well, the problem lies in **1.**

What happens if you do the following?

```
var results = Enumerable.Empty<Project>().AsQueryable();
string pId = "1";
results = results.Where("Id.ToString().Contains(@0)", pId);
```

If it fails, you'll have **confirmed** it's a problem with Dynamic Linq alone (i.e. it doesn't support the expression you're feeding it), so you'll have to dig into it and patch it.

Semi-related: the `ToStringGenerator` looks useful; could you submit a patch for NHibernate? http://jira.nhforge.org

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have done what you suggested and the query works fine (I mean it yields no results but the Expression inside the query is correctly generated). 
Something that I have noticed now comparing the 2 queries is that the Expression for the static one uses a Expression.Constant with the variable (pId) value whereas the dynamic one uses the string value directly. Do you think this may have to do with the problem?

Comment: @murki: yes, it might be related. High-impedance expression trees are extremely fragile in their support for small variations. Now, given this you have two paths: patching Dynamic Linq to emit an Expression.Constant, or patching NHibernate to support the usage emitted by Dynamic Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the property `Id` of the class `Project` it's an `Int32` try registering the corresponding `Int32.ToString()` method in your `ToStringGenerator` class.

```
...
public ToStringGenerator()
{
    SupportedMethods = new[]
        {
            ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition<object>(x => x.ToString()),
            ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition<int>(x => x.ToString()),
        };
}
...
```

Comment: Yeah, it's an Int32, but I'd actually tried that before -and this is probably topic for another question, but: 1) if I put only object and int nothing changes in my error, 2) if i start putting more data types (e.g. DateTime), it throws an NhibernateException with the error "An item with the same key has already been added" when building the SessionFactory.

Comment: Ok thanks. After some investigation, NHibernate 3.2, still in beta version, will have a built in ToString support in Linq.